# Finding missing sequence number in SQL 2008 table

Tags: sql-server-2008

I have a table that return the below by this query:

```
SELECT *    
  FROM [PROC_MN]    
  where PO_NO='GV17885' AND DOC_NO='622843' 

ID  PO_NO   DOC_NO  PROCESS_SEQ PROCESS_NAME    STATUS  TIME
756 GV17885 622843  2   R.M.Requisition Start   23-04-18 15:29
788 GV17885 622843  2   R.M.Requisition Finish  23-04-18 15:50
289 GV17885 622843  1   CTP Start   23-04-18 8:57
426 GV17885 622843  1   CTP Finish  23-04-18 10:09
901 GV17885 622843  3   Material Cut    Start   23-04-18 17:23
903 GV17885 622843  3   Material Cut    Finish  23-04-18 17:26
1669    GV17885 622843  4   Print   Start   24-04-18 13:59
1712    GV17885 622843  4   Print   Finish  24-04-18 14:44
3421    GV17885 622843  5   Q.C Start   27-04-18 8:04
3492    GV17885 622843  5   Q.C Finish  27-04-18 8:42
3630    GV17885 622843  7   RFID    Start   27-04-18 9:36
3632    GV17885 622843  7   RFID    Finish  27-04-18 9:38
4264    GV17885 622843  8   Q.C Start   27-04-18 14:58
4288    GV17885 622843  8   Q.C Finish  27-04-18 15:16
4729    GV17885 622843  9   Encode  Start   28-04-18 8:48
4734    GV17885 622843  9   Encode  Finish  28-04-18 8:49
4698    GV17885 622843  9   Encode  Start   28-04-18 8:24
4722    GV17885 622843  9   Encode  Finish  28-04-18 8:47
5016    GV17885 622843  10  Q.C Start   28-04-18 13:38
5073    GV17885 622843  10  Q.C Finish  28-04-18 14:11
```

I want to find the missing PROCESS_SEQ row, with the above result we found that the missing PROCESS_SEQ is number 6 . I use the following query but it return nothing/. Please help!

```
SET NOCOUNT ON;

DECLARE @Min BIGINT
DECLARE @Max BIGINT
DECLARE @i BIGINT
```

IF OBJECT_ID('tempdb..#TempTable') IS NOT NULL 
        BEGIN
            DROP TABLE #TempTable
        END

```
CREATE TABLE #TempTable
    (
      TempOrderNumber BIGINT
    )

SELECT  @Min = ( SELECT MIN([PROCESS_SEQ])
                 FROM   [PROC_MN] WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE PO_NO='GV17885' AND [DOC_NO]='622843')
SELECT  @Max = ( SELECT MAX([PROCESS_SEQ])
                 FROM   [PROC_MN] WITH ( NOLOCK )
                 WHERE PO_NO='GV17885' AND [DOC_NO]='622843')
SELECT  @i = @Min

WHILE @i <= @Max 
    BEGIN
        INSERT  INTO #TempTable
                SELECT  @i

        SELECT  @i = @i + 1

    END

SELECT  TempOrderNumber
FROM    #TempTable
        LEFT JOIN [PROC_MN] o WITH ( NOLOCK ) ON tempordernumber = o.[PROCESS_SEQ]
WHERE   o.[PROCESS_SEQ] IS NULL
```

Comment: Do you need all the missing numbers at once? Or just the first one?

Comment: I need all missing seq number in the  PO_NO=? AND [DOC_NO]=?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You may try the following query:

```
WITH
    [MISSING_RANGES] AS
    (
        SELECT
            [MISSING_RANGE_NO] = ROW_NUMBER() OVER (ORDER BY P.[PO_NO], P.[DOC_NO], P.[PROCESS_SEQ]),
            P.[PO_NO],
            P.[DOC_NO],
            [FIRST_MISSING] = P.[PROCESS_SEQ] + 1,
            [LAST_MISSING] = N.[PROCESS_SEQ] - 1
        FROM
            [PROC_MN] AS P
            OUTER APPLY (SELECT [PROCESS_SEQ] = MIN([PROCESS_SEQ])
                         FROM [PROC_MN]
                         WHERE
                             [PO_NO] = P.[PO_NO] AND
                             [DOC_NO] = P.[DOC_NO] AND
                             [PROCESS_SEQ] > P.[PROCESS_SEQ]) AS N
        WHERE
            N.[PROCESS_SEQ] > P.[PROCESS_SEQ] + 1
    ),
    [MISSING_SEQUENCES] AS
    (
        SELECT
            [MISSING_RANGE_NO],
            [MISSING_PROCESS_SEQ] = [FIRST_MISSING]
        FROM
            [MISSING_RANGES]
    UNION ALL
        SELECT
            R.[MISSING_RANGE_NO],
            S.[MISSING_PROCESS_SEQ] + 1
        FROM
            [MISSING_RANGES] AS R
            INNER JOIN [MISSING_SEQUENCES] AS S ON S.[MISSING_RANGE_NO] = R.[MISSING_RANGE_NO]
        WHERE
            S.[MISSING_PROCESS_SEQ] < R.[LAST_MISSING]
    )
SELECT DISTINCT
    R.[PO_NO],
    R.[DOC_NO],
    S.[MISSING_PROCESS_SEQ]
FROM
    [MISSING_RANGES] AS R
    INNER JOIN [MISSING_SEQUENCES] AS S ON S.[MISSING_RANGE_NO] = R.[MISSING_RANGE_NO]
--WHERE
--    R.[PO_NO] = ? AND
--    R.[DOC_NO] = ?
ORDER BY
    R.[PO_NO],
    R.[DOC_NO],
    S.[MISSING_PROCESS_SEQ]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 10000);
```

(I put the WHERE clause to filter for specific [PO_NO] AND [DOC_NO] values in comment for testing purposes.)

**Edit (in response to the additional updated post):**

This is my personal version of your SQL-script. Just like yours, it generates a temp table containing a sequence (from minimum to maximum) and selects all values where the record from the data table cannot be joined:

```
DECLARE @PO_NO VARCHAR(10) = 'GV17885';
DECLARE @DOC_NO VARCHAR(10) = '622843';

DECLARE @TempTable TABLE
(
    [TempOrderNumber] BIGINT PRIMARY KEY
);

DECLARE @Min BIGINT;
DECLARE @Max BIGINT;

SELECT
    @Min = MIN([PROCESS_SEQ]),
    @Max = MAX([PROCESS_SEQ])
FROM
    [PROC_MN] WITH (NOLOCK)
WHERE
    [PO_NO] = @PO_NO AND
    [DOC_NO] = @DOC_NO;

DECLARE @i BIGINT = @Min;

WHILE (@i <= @Max) BEGIN
    INSERT INTO @TempTable ([TempOrderNumber])
    SELECT @i;

    SET @i += 1;
END;

SELECT
    [TempOrderNumber]
FROM
    @TempTable
    LEFT JOIN [PROC_MN] AS O WITH (NOLOCK) ON
        [TempOrderNumber] = O.[PROCESS_SEQ]
        AND O.[PO_NO] = @PO_NO
        AND O.[DOC_NO] = @DOC_NO
WHERE
    O.[PROCESS_SEQ] IS NULL;
```

This should work correctly too. But I personally prefer my original query, since it is based on set operations instead of loops.

Comment: return nothing, please see my EDITED query, but it still return nothing.

Comment: I will look at your update. But does it also return nothing when executed in SQL Server Management Studio without the WHERE clause? (I tested it with a sample table (containing dummy values for the three used fields and that worked fine.)

Comment: With the above sample data , I used your query but it returned nothing. Dont know why?

Comment: Very strange. I tested it again, this time with your specific data sample. Then it generates two identical records, both with missing value 6. (Probably because there are always two records with the same values of [PO_NO], [DOC_NO] and [PROCESS_SEQ]: one with status 'Start' and one with status 'Finish'.  So my query probably needs an additional DISTINCT in the SELECT clause.) I have no idea (yet) why it does not return any results in your database...

Comment: I looked at your updated post. Should work. Almost. One detail. You might want to filter the correct [PO_NO] and [DOC_NO] values in your final join too. Then it will give the correct result too.

Comment: Yes, I already update the Where condition. I'm sure it is correct. ANd the sample data is also correct, it is real data, but it return nothing

Comment: Note that there is a subtle difference if you check your [PO_NO] and [DOC_NO] columns in the WHERE clause or in the LEFT JOIN's ON clause...!... You only want to join records from the data table with the correct [PO_NO] and [DOC_NO] values, so you should not put them in the WHERE, but in the ON...